# Reverse jquery animation

Tags: jquery, css

How can i make reverse this animation?

So the boxes shouldn't move from top to bottom, but when you scroll, they should appear from bottom up to top.. they should just move the opposite direction!

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eaqrn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line's `marginTop:30`

```
$(this).stop().animate({opacity:1, marginTop:30},'slow');
```

to

```
$(this).stop().animate({opacity:1, marginTop:-30},'slow');
```